# How could I load content from one Craft install into a template of another

Tags: entries

We are working on a help guide solution for Craft and our hope is to have all the guide content live in a single master Craft setup and then our client's sites could read and display this content in their admins through a custom plugin.

We have the rough outlines of a proof of concept for it, the missing piece is sharing the content.  We are thinking of using RSS or JSON to do this but wanted to see if there was any other ways we should consider?

Comment: Is your help guide solution going to be on the same server as your client's or different?

Comment: On a different server sadly

Comment: Does there need to be some authentication/authorization to read the data, or is it public?

Comment: It can be public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your idea of RSS or JSON would work fine.

The only reason I can think of to use RSS over JSON would be if there was a possibility you wanted RSS readers to be able to consume the content as well.  Otherwise, I'd just stick with JSON and expose it over a web accessible API.